# Как спарсить отдельные данные андроид приложения?

Tags: javascript, java, android

Всем привет. Как можно спарсить отдельные выходные данные андроид приложения?

Условия:

1. Приложение установлено и запущено на устройстве андроид (важно! Не эмулятор).

Рассмотрим на примере "Яндекс Go водитель такси". (Приложение запущено и водитель находится на линии).

1. Приходит заказ. Взял заказ.
2. По итогу завершения появляется окно с прибылью за заказ.

Вот как эту сумму пристроить в своё приложение?

PS: Учусь java, буду писать приложение для себя, по сбору статистики и реальным заработаным деньгам в яндексе. А то яндекс оставляет все за спиной, а таблицу вести добавляя каждый заказ долго.

Может есть некое приложение под андроид, что бы спарсить переменную или граббер.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Думаю законно - ни как, если у яндекса нет api для этого.

Comment: @Михаил Принято. Спасибо за инфу.